# Multiple time zones on Nexus 4 - Android 4.2.2

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4

Is it possible to set two different time zones on nexus 4-android 4.2.2 version?

I want to set-up EST (Eastern Standard Time) & IST (Indian Standard Time)...

Thank you

Comment: Where do you use two different time zones? For instance, do you have some kind of a clock app on desktop where it displays times in multiple time zones, according to your choice?

Answer (score 1):

Of course.

Open the clock app. On the bottom bar you'll see three icons, one for alarm ,one for place and one for menu. Click the middle one. Select the cities you want and those time will be added to the clock.

Comment: Thanks alot. i can see 2 different multiple time zones. However is there a way that i can see both time zones on homescreen or notification bar. Instead of opening the clock app every time....

Comment: For homescreen: Re size the clock widget and you'll be able to see both the time zone. For notification you have to install 3rd party software.